# Nose: How to skip tests by default?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I am using Python's nose and I have marked some of my tests as "slow", as explained in the [attrib plugin documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html).

I would like to skip all "slow" Tests by default when running `nosetests`, i.e. without having to write `nosetests -a '!slow'`. But I want to be able to run these tests when explicitly running them or writing `nosetests -a 'slow'`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Options are the same as on the command line, with the -- prefix removed" (https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#configuration)

A file `setup.cfg` with the following contents should work:

```
[nosetests]
attr=!speed=slow
```

Comment: It follows that multiple such values must be comma-delimited (no space). E.g. `attr=!foo,!bar`.