# Nose: Using a boolean to choose tests with a default setting

Tags: python, nose

My question is very much like this question: [Nose: How to skip tests by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674713/nose-how-to-skip-tests-by-default)

The difference is that I want to have a default setting to skip the slow tests. That is, when I don't specify an attribute it should skip the slow tests. When I however specify the slow attribute I want to run only the slow tests. Is there a way to do this with nose (python)?

Comment: your question is exactly the same as the one you linked to. What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is that in the example you have one set of tests that you want to run all the time, and when you add a flag you want the first set of tests to run as well as the slow ones. I have to seperate sets of tests, and I want only one of the to run at a time. To be more specific to my problem: I have some tests communicating with a peripheral, and some tests only using a simulation of that peripheral. So I want the tests communicating with the peripheral to be the "standard", but when I set a "simulation"-flag I want only the simulation tests to be run.